# How can you stop arrow symbols being corrupted when producing a knitr::kable() through a .bat file?

Tags: r, batch-file, kable, kableextra

I'm trying to generate a table using `knitr::kable` and `kableExtra` with arrow symbols within the output table. I've got it working when I run manually through RStudio, but I'd like to be able to automate the running of the script through a `.bat` file. When I try this, the arrows become strange characters (see link below). Anyone have any ideas what might be causing this or how I could make the arrows show properly?

Thanks legends!!

[output_showing_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44jP1.png)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Subject, ~Fatigue,  ~Pain.Areas,
        1L,      "",           NA,
        2L,      "↓",           NA,
        3L,      "",           NA,
        4L,      "",           NA,
        5L,      "", "Lower back",
        6L,      "↑",           NA,
        7L,      "",           NA,
        8L,      "",           NA,
        9L,      "",           NA,
       10L,      "↓",        "Hip",
       11L,      "",           NA,
       12L,      "",           NA,
       13L,      "",           NA,
       14L,      "↑",           NA,
       15L,      "↓",           NA,
       16L,      "",      "Groin",
       17L,      "",           NA,
       18L,      "↑",           NA,
       19L,      "",           NA,
       20L,      "↑",           NA
  )


data %>%
  mutate(Pain.Areas = ifelse(is.na(Pain.Areas), "", Pain.Areas)) %>%
  kable("html", align = "c", escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped"), full_width = F)
```

.bat file code is:

```
cd "C:\Users\My.Name\OneDrive\R projects\Project.Directory" 
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\Users\My.Name\OneDrive\R projects\Project.Directory\script.R"
```

Comment: Where is your `.bat` file code then? We cannot tell you what to fix or how to fix it, if we cannot see it!

Comment: My mistake @Compo,  added .bat file code to the original post. It is here also:


`cd "C:\Users\My.Name\OneDrive\R projects\Project.Directory" 
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\Users\My.Name\OneDrive\R projects\Project.Directory\script.R"`

Comment: Your link doesn't work. And it should be in your question AS TEXT.

Comment: Sorry @Mark, I'm not sure what you mean by 'as text'? It's an image of a table. The imgur link is working for me? How do you suggest I fix the link?

Comment: My best guess is that you're missing a methodology for outputting unicode text.